# java - HttpServlet file download

Tags: java, web

I tried to create a file, write to it and then turn the file into an input stream and transfer its bytes to the output stream of the HTTP response. But I get the message "/tmp/mozilla_xxxx/33JJ1OHw.md.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read." when testing it.

Here's the code that does this part.

```
        f = new File("f.md");
        f.createNewFile();
        fw = new FileWriter(f);
        fw.append("#" + query + "\n" + queryResult);
        fw.close();
        resp.setContentType("text/markdown");

        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
          out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        in.close();
        out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation, **[File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String))** class is not meant to read the actual file content, it is just...

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

But, there are many ways of getting file's content, just use one of the following classes: **FileReader, BufferedReader, Scanner and Files**.

Here you'll see different examples to do that, just use the one you find better. [Different ways of Reading a text file in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/)